# Creating AS400 Class to implement in vb.net application

Tags: vb.net, class, oop, module

I am trying to automate AS400 using a vb.net application. When I am creating the objects in a module, it works without any problem. The code inside a module is as below:

```
Module Module1
    Public autECLPSObj As Object
    Public autECLConnList As Object
    Public autECLOIAObj As Object
    Public autECLWinMetrics As Object
    Public SetEmulatorReady As Boolean
    Public Sub Create(ByVal Session as String)
        autECLPSObj = CreateObject("PCOMM.auteclps")
        autECLConnList = CreateObject("PCOMM.auteclconnlist")
        autECLOIAObj = CreateObject("PCOMM.autecloia")
        autECLWinMetrics = CreateObject("PCOMM.auteclwinmetrics")
        Session = UCase(Session)
        If autECLConnList.FindConnectionByName(Session) Is Nothing Then
            SetEmulatorReady = False
            Exit Function
        End If
        autECLPSObj.SetConnectionByName(Session)
        autECLOIAObj.SetConnectionByName(Session)
        autECLWinMetrics.SetConnectionByName(Session)
        autECLPSObj.auteclfieldlist.Refresh
        autECLConnList.Refresh
        SetEmulatorReady = True
    End Sub
End Module
```

But I am trying to create a class and inside the new constructor I want to create the connection as below:

```
Public Class UNET

    Dim autECLPSObj As Object
    Dim autECLConnList As Object
    Dim autECLOIAObj As Object
    Dim autECLWinMetrics As Object
    Private boolEmulatorConnectionState As Boolean
    Public Property SetEmulatorReady As Boolean
        Get
            Return boolEmulatorConnectionState
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            boolEmulatorConnectionState = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Sub New(ByVal Session As String)
        Dim strEmulator
        strEmulator = Session.ToUpper()
        autECLPSObj = Nothing
        autECLConnList = Nothing
        autECLOIAObj = Nothing


        autECLPSObj = CreateObject("PCOMM.auteclps")
        autECLConnList = CreateObject("PCOMM.auteclconnlist")
        autECLOIAObj = CreateObject("PCOMM.autecloia")
        autECLWinMetrics = CreateObject("PCOMM.auteclwinmetrics")

        If autECLConnList.FindConnectionByName(strEmulator) Is Nothing Then

            SetEmulatorReady = False
        Else
            autECLPSObj.SetConnectionByName(Session)
            autECLOIAObj.SetConnectionByName(Session)
            autECLWinMetrics.SetConnectionByName(Session)
            autECLPSObj.auteclfieldlist.Refresh
            autECLConnList.Refresh
            strWindowTitle = autECLWinMetrics.WindowTitle
            SetEmulatorReady = True
        End If

    End Sub
    Private strWindowTitle As String
    Public Property WindowTitle As String
        Get
            Return strWindowTitle
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            strWindowTitle = value
        End Set
    End Property


End Class
```

While using this the CreateObject is not working, getting error

'CreateObject is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Also tried

```
autECLPSObj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("PCOMM.auteclps"))
autECLConnList = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("PCOMM.auteclconnlist"))
autECLOIAObj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("PCOMM.autecloia"))
autECLWinMetrics = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("PCOMM.auteclwinmetrics"))
```

It creates the object however, generates error when I am trying to get the WindowTitle in

```
strWindowTitle = autECLWinMetrics.WindowTitle
```

It says the Target process exited with code 3221226356 while evaluating the function 'autECLWinMetrics.WindowTitle'.

Even taking the reference of AS400 and declaring the variables as

```
Dim autECLPSObj As AutPSTypeLibrary.AutPS
Dim autECLConnList As AutConnListTypeLibrary.AutConnList
Dim autECLOIAObj As AutOIATypeLibrary.AutOIA
Dim autECLWinMetrics As AutWinMetricsTypeLibrary.AutWinMetrics
```

didn't help and generated same error at

```
autECLWinMetrics.WindowTitle
```

Am I missing something? I want to create this class so that while creating an Object of UNET by using

```
Dim U As New UNET("A")
If U.SetEmulatorReady Then
    MsgBox(U.WindowTitle)
Else
    MsgBox("Not created")
End If
```

So that I can implement the OOPS concept completely. Please help.

Comment: Have you looked into using ADO.net https://www.connectionstrings.com/as-400/

Comment: The issue is not with the connection to ADO.net, the issue occurs when the objects are created inside a class, but works fine when created inside a module.

Comment: Have a look at the comment here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.createobject?view=netcore-3.1 - "cannot be used to create instances of classes in Visual Basic unless those classes are explicitly exposed as COM components"

Comment: The class of AS400 can be exposed as COM components and that's why the object can be created inside a module as I expressed in the question. Just unable to understand why the objects can't be created properly when tried inside a custom class and so I posted here to know if anyone can highlight on that, or may be there is other ways around to create the objects inside a custom class which I might not know.